# How to display full day of month from the selected month using Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

When I select a month and year from select box.

How to display all days of that month?

**My code**

```
` <select class="form-control" name="amonth" id="amonth">
          <option value="0">Select Month</option>
          <option value="1">January</option>
          <option value="2">February</option>
          <option value="3">March</option>
          <option value="4">April</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">June</option>
          <option value="7">July</option>
          <option value="8">August</option>
          <option value="9">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December </option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control" name="ayear" id="ayear">
          <option value="0">Select Year</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
           <option value="2016">2016</option>
        </select>
```

If I select july 2015

I want display all dates 1/07/2015 to 31/07/2015 in 1 column.

I get select name from this code

```
$amonth = Input::get('amonth');
$ayear = Input::get('ayear');
```

but I don't know how to display full day of month.

Answer (score 0):

You can get count of days in month by function date with format character "t":

**Controller:**

```
$dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-'. $amonth . '-' . $ayear));
// in case of july 2015 it will be 31

$days = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++) {
    $days[] = sprintf('%02d/%02d/%04d', $i, $amonth, $ayear);
}
//....
View::make('yourView', [...., 'days' => $days]);
```

**View**:

```
....
{{implode('<br />', $days)}}
....
```

For more information see:
[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Hope this is help.

Comment: thank you sir its work ,but this code add in controller page its work fine.when im add in view (blde.php) page its not work. how to solve i want in view page.

Comment: its fine,, how to check $days is in database or not? i eg: select july 2015, then 1/70/2015 to 15/07/2015 days are in database or not? how to check each days in database?